# sorting a QAbstractTableModel and expose it to qml

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, tableview, qml

I need to create an integration between `Qt` and `qml`, where from `Qt` I ask for some info to a server, create a `tablemodel` from `Qt` and expose the info to `qml`. I've reached this point, but now I've to sort the info. I'm using a `QSortFilterProxyModel`, most of the examples I've found are created for Widgets, and create the `tableview` from `Qt`, but when I tried to create it from `qml`, there's not an option `"setSortingEnabled"`, in the `qml` I've many objects no just the `TableView`. I have used the order `model->sort(1, Qt:AscendingOrder)` but there is not change in the `qml` screen

SimMainWindow.cpp

```
#include "SimMainWindow.h"
#include "TurnDisplayTable.h"
#include "TurnDisplayItem.h"
#include <QtQml>
#include <QGraphicsObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDeclarativeView>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <tablemodel.h>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>

SimMainWindow::SimMainWindow(int argc, char **argv): QGuiApplication(argc, argv), view()
{
  qDebug() << "begin"; ///////////////////////////////

  qmlRegisterType<TurnDisplayTable>("TurnDisplayTable", 1,0, "TurnDisplayTable");

  filesModel= new TurnDisplayTable();
  view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("idFilesModel", filesModel);
  proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
  proxyModel->setSourceModel(filesModel);
  proxyModel->sort(1, Qt::AscendingOrder);

  view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("pModel", proxyModel);

  view.setSource( QUrl::fromLocalFile("./ui/main.qml") );

  QObject::connect((QObject*)view.rootObject(), SIGNAL(refreshMsg()), this, SLOT(refreshHome()));
  QObject::connect((QObject*)view.rootObject(), SIGNAL(changeMsg()), this, SLOT(changeHome()));
  QObject::connect((QObject*)view.rootObject(), SIGNAL(sortMsg()), this, SLOT(sortHome()));
  QObject::connect((QObject*)view.rootObject(), SIGNAL(infoMsg(QString, QString)), this, SLOT(infoHome(QString, QString)));




  view.show();

  qDebug() << "end"; ///////////////////////////////
}


SimMainWindow::~SimMainWindow()
{}

void SimMainWindow::refreshHome()
{
  qDebug() << "refresh";
  QList<TurnDisplayItem> list;
  QString  turn = "2";
  QString  date = "septiembre";
  TurnDisplayItem item(turn, date);
  list << item;

  turn = "4";
  date = "mayo";
  TurnDisplayItem item2(turn, date);
  list << item2;

  turn = "1";
  date = "julio";
  TurnDisplayItem item3(turn, date);
  list << item3;

  turn = "3";
  date = "abril";
  TurnDisplayItem item4(turn, date);
  list << item4;

  turn = "2";
  date = "mayo";
  TurnDisplayItem item5(turn, date);
  list << item5;


  filesModel->setCurrencyMap(list);
  proxyModel->setSourceModel(filesModel);
  proxyModel->sort(1, Qt::AscendingOrder);
}

void SimMainWindow::changeHome()
{
  qDebug() << "cambio";
  QList<TurnDisplayItem> list;
  QString  turn = "3";
  QString  date = "sep";
  TurnDisplayItem item(turn, date);
  list << item;

  turn = "1";
  date = "may";
  TurnDisplayItem item2(turn, date);
  list << item2;

  turn = "2";
  date = "jul";
  TurnDisplayItem item3(turn, date);
  list << item3;

  turn = "6";
  date = "abr";
  TurnDisplayItem item4(turn, date);
  list << item4;

  turn = "9";
  date = "oct";
  TurnDisplayItem item5(turn, date);
  list << item5;


  filesModel->setCurrencyMap(list);
}

void SimMainWindow::sortHome()
{
  proxyModel->sort(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
  view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("pModel", proxyModel);
  qDebug()<< "sort...";
  view.show();
}

void SimMainWindow::infoHome(const QString &turnH, const QString &dateH)
{
  qDebug() << "info";
  QList<TurnDisplayItem> list;
  QString  turn = turnH;
  QString  date = dateH;
  TurnDisplayItem item(turn, date);
  list << item;

  filesModel->setCurrencyMap(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works in my case:

```
Model model;

QSortFilterProxyModel proxyModel;
proxyModel.setSortRole(Model::YOURCUSTOM_ROLE_HERE);
proxyModel.setSourceModel(&model);
proxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(true);
proxyModel.sort(0);
```

I suspect your model is not sorting because you have to set the target role by setting `setSortRole(int role)` and appling `void QSortFilterProxyModel::sort(int column, Qt::SortOrder order = Qt::AscendingOrder) [virtual]`.

I hope this solve your problem.